# Unable to subclass NSTextStorage

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin + TextKit to create an editor with Syntax Highlighting feature. When I try to add `LayoutManager` to my custom `NSTextStorage`, It crash the app with the following message:

```
Xamarin.iOS: Received unhandled ObjectiveC exception: NSInvalidArgumentException *** -string only defined for abstract class. Define -[Thomas_Editor_SyntaxRenderer string]!
```

I try to `[Export("***")]` some override methods of my custom class but they keep crashing my app. I don't know to fix the bug.

Can someone tell me how to fix the problem? I had uploaded a sample code on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b431dda2ae675bb3f32e40075a620ca1).

Comment: Could you share the code snippet? It will help us to identify the problem

Comment: @Prashant Thanks. I have created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b431dda2ae675bb3f32e40075a620ca1), here you go.